# Data Annonation Lost in Joined Linq Select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have two Tables as master and detail . I set some attribute Like :
`[DisplayName="Customer Name"]` and ..... 
when I fill my **Datagridview** source or **Reporting service** source or ... with selected list , I can use the attributes and it set my header column and many usefull other think . but if I want  Flatt my master detail and write linq select like :

```
  var x = from m in master 
  join d in detail on m.id equal d.masterId
  select new {d.Id , d.Name , m.Date, m.Customer}
```

I have no access to defined attributes .
What can I do ? 
I don't like write ViewClass for each select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to create a new Modal/ Class Like **MasterDetails** , which will hold all the properties you want in your page to view and apply the attributes on that new **MasterDetails** class and then write a new linq like .

```
  var x = from m in master 
  join d in detail on m.id equal d.masterId
  select new  MasterDetails {Id=d.Id ,Name= d.Name ,Date= m.Date,Customer= m.Customer}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: If I do this , I had to write a **ViewClass** for each view that I want (Or each joined select ... think if my data in more than two table and I joined them) . why the attributes dispose ?

Comment: attribute is not disposed , but its only associated with the class object , so what do you think is the type of `select new {d.Id , d.Name , m.Date, m.Customer}`? This is an anonymous type .

Comment: so yes ,  if you are using some hybrid , data type kind of thing in your View and you want to use Attribute , you have to create a new class (ViewClass) ,